# How to use addOnScrollListener with different lists in one activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, onscrolllistener

In my app, there are two methods `getData` and `getItemsByLabel`. Each one is getting different lists by retrofit Callback method, and I used the navigation drawer method `onNavigationItemSelected` so that whenever a user clicks on a particular item, a different list is displayed in the `RecyclerView`.

The problem is that I use a method `addOnScrollListener` to detect scroll behavior from any list on `RecyclerView` which causes the items overlapping in the displayed list.

Hence the problem is when scrolling down occurs, the items from the main list and the list of the selected category/item are overlapping.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    // Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));
    // I'm also creating a log message, which we'll look at in more detail later
    // Crashlytics.log("MainActivity started");

    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
    adapter = new PostAdapter(this, items);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.home);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryGreen));
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).isChecked()) {
                if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(MainActivity.this)) {
                    getData();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText
                            (MainActivity.this, "You must connect to the Internet to update the list"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                    if (navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).isChecked()) {
                        getItemsByLabel(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 3000);
        }

    });

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                isScrolling = true;
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)) {
                    isScrolling = false;
                    getData(); // This is where I call getData <--
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (Utils.hasNetworkAccess(this)) {
        getData();
    } else {
        if (runtimeExceptionDaoItems == null || runtimeExceptionDaoItems.queryForAll().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There's no data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            items.addAll(runtimeExceptionDaoItems.queryForAll());
            Toast.makeText(this, "From Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

long lastPress;
Toast backpressToast;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime - lastPress > 5000) {
            backpressToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            backpressToast.show();
            lastPress = currentTime;
        } else {
            if (backpressToast != null) backpressToast.cancel();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.searchForPosts));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String keyword) {
            getItemsBySearch(keyword);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String keyword) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(() -> {
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getData();
        return false;
    });

    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            getData();
            break;
        case R.id.accessory:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.accessory);
            getItemsByLabel("Accessory");
            break;
        case R.id.arcade:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.arcade);
            getItemsByLabel("Arcade");
            break;
        case R.id.fashion:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.fashion);
            getItemsByLabel("Fashion");
            break;
        case R.id.food:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.food);
            getItemsByLabel("Food");
            break;
        case R.id.heath:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.heath);
            getItemsByLabel("Heath");
            break;
        case R.id.lifeStyle:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.lifestyle);
            getItemsByLabel("Lifestyle");
            break;
        case R.id.sports:
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.sports);
            getItemsByLabel("Sports");
            break;
        case R.id.settings:
            break;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void getData() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = BloggerAPI.BASE_URL + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.KEY;

    if (token != "") {
        url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
    }
    if (token == null) {
        return;
    }

    final Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList(url);
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Response<PostList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                PostList list = response.body();
                if (list != null) {
                    token = list.getNextPageToken();
                    items.addAll(list.getItems());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                int sc = response.code();
                switch (sc) {
                    case 400:
                        Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getCause());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

//=============================================================================================

public void getItemsByLabel(String label) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = BloggerAPI.BASE_URL + "search?q=label:" + label + "&key=" + BloggerAPI.KEY;

    Log.e("Label :", url);

    if (token != "") {
        url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
    }
    if (token == null) {
        return;
    }

    final Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList(url);
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Response<PostList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                items.clear();
                recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);
                PostList list = response.body();
                if (list != null) {
                    token = list.getNextPageToken();
                    items.addAll(list.getItems());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int sc = response.code();
                switch (sc) {
                    case 400:
                        Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getCause());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Methods that I tried to solve this problem :

1. Implementing `ScrollListener` inside each method `getData` and `getItemsByLabel`
2. Creating a fragment for each item on the navigation drawer menu and implement `ScrollListener` on it.
3. And finally, I put for loop on `onScrolled` method to detect which item on the drawer menu is checked to get the list it's own. But unfortunately, none is working.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the question... How many list are there? When is addOnScrollListener() called? Where's the creation of the RecyclerViews?

Comment: @luca-murra the MainActivity class is too large, I didn't attached it all so as not to distract the code reader, however, If this will help I'll edit the code and attached it

Comment: Now it's better, but I think I didn't understand what's the problem

Comment: The method **getData** gets main list and view it, on navigation drawer menu there's a seven categories, when a user click on a specific category/item, the method **getItemsByLabel(String label);** is called and view list depending on the string parameter giving to it, (This means that there are seven different lists in addition to the main list generated by getData method) the problem here is that when scrolling down occurs the items overlapping in the displayed list between the main list and the main list and the list of the selected category / item

Comment: this because the ScrollListener detect the scrolling behavior regardless of the selected menu.
I hope I have clarified the problem and apologize for the prolongation

Comment: Can you please check my answer below?

Comment: can you add an image/screenshot of your problem?

Comment: @imtiaz-abir this is a quick explanation of the problem again in pictures, For example I will choose the section for the accessories to display its own posts, the last two posts from first ten posts loaded is 
"16 amazing accessory pictures", "20 ideas you can steal from storage devices [image01](https://i.imgur.com/ykBfKzu.png)
I marked with blue color as items of label/section chosen, and red color for items that overlapping with it from home/main items [image02](https://i.imgur.com/lCjPOTq.png)
[image03](https://i.imgur.com/zxmxgUe.png)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think the problem is arising for adding the common `addOnScrollListener` to your `RecyclerView`. I think this problem is occurring due to the implementation of control flow and for the race condition among threads while fetching the lists using API calls. Let me describe my idea briefly.

Both APIs called in `getData` and `getItemsByLabel` functions are asynchronous and hence you cannot assure when the API call returns with the data. Hence let us think about the following scenario:

1. `getItemsByLabel` called when you clicked an item in the navigation drawer.
2. In the meantime, `onScrolled` function got called somehow and the API for `getData` triggered immediately.
3. `getItemsByLabel` function returned with data, cleared the `items` list and started inserting new data to the `items`.
4. The `getData` API returned at the same time just after the data in the `items` list was cleared by `getItemsByLabel` and start adding elements in `items`.
5. Thus the `items` list has elements from both `getData` and `getItemsByLabel`.
6. The `ArrayList` implementation is not thread-safe, hence it is prone to have data mix from both of the API response.

I hope that explains the problem that you are having. To avoid this problem, you might consider having a `boolean` variable like `getItemsByLabelCalled` which might have value `false` by default. When an item is being clicked in the navigation drawer, set the value of `getItemsByLabelCalled = true`. Then check this value before adding elements into `items` list in the following to cases.

1. Inside the `getData` function. `if(getItemsByLabelCalled) return`
2. Inside the `getItemsByLabel` function, set and reset the value of `getItemsByLabelCalled`. Please check the following code in the UPDATE section.

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE**

To give you a sample demonstration of what changes you should make:

Take the `boolean` for keeping track when the function is called.

```
private boolean getItemsByLabelCalled = false;
```

Now, modify the `getData` function like the following.

```
private void getData() {
    if(getItemsByLabelCalled) return;

    // Other statements are the same as before
}
```

Now modify the `getItemsByLabel` function to set the `getItemsByLabelCalled` variable.

```
public void getItemsByLabel(String label) {

    // Here is the change
    if(getItemsByLabelCalled) return; 
    else getItemsByLabelCalled = true;

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = BloggerAPI.BASE_URL + "search?q=label:" + label + "&key=" + BloggerAPI.KEY;

    Log.e("Label :", url);

    if (token != "") {
        url = url + "&pageToken=" + token;
    }
    if (token == null) {
        return;
    }

    final Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList(url);
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Response<PostList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                items.clear();
                recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);
                PostList list = response.body();
                if (list != null) {
                    token = list.getNextPageToken();
                    items.addAll(list.getItems());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // Reset again here
                getItemsByLabelCalled = false;
            } else {
                // Reset again here
                getItemsByLabelCalled = false;

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int sc = response.code();
                switch (sc) {
                    case 400:
                        Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getCause());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Reset again here
            getItemsByLabelCalled = false;
        }
    });
}
```

I think no more changes are required, though I am not sure. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for analyzing the code, although it seems logical in theory but unfortunately did not work with me,
At first you said "Inside the onScrolled function. If (getItemsByLabelCalled) <- Do not call the getData function."
I made the following
if (getItemsByLabelCalled) {
                             for (int i = 1; i <7; i ++) {
                                 getItemsByLabel (navigationView.getMenu (). getItem (i) .getTitle (). toString ());
                             }
                         } else {
                             getData ();
                         }

Comment: `if (getItemsByLabelCalled) return;` this is what I suggested. What were you trying to do? Where the looping came from?

Comment: I called getItemsByLabel and passed the string value from the title of drawer menu.
On second step I doing like you said,`if(getItemsByLabelCalled){
                            return;
                        }`
3. setting `getItemsByLabelCalled = false` on `getItemsByLabel`

Comment: You do not have to call `getItemsByLabel` inside the `getData` function. Let me update the answer for you for a sample demonstration.

Comment: Inside the `onScrolled` function
I created the for loop to looping on the seven items on Navigation drawer menu! this Why I doing that

Comment: this causes stop scrolling for all seven items in navigation drawer menu, only ten items is displayed, if I remove looping from `onScrolled` the same problem is still existing.
<br/>Anyway thanks again for trying to solve it.

Comment: I hope I could make you understand why the overlapping problem was occurring. It's difficult to solve the actual problem without having the full code. However, StackOverflow is not ideal for sharing the whole code and it encourages to post specific problems requiring a specific answer. I hope, I answered the question correctly even if it did not solve the overall problem that you are having. Let me know if you need any further assistance. I will be very glad to help. :)

Comment: I understood the problem but unfortunately I could not solve it, of course I have no problem viewing the full code if you can help me, we can complete our discussion in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189024/discussion-between-dr-mido-and-reaz-murshed)

Comment: Hi
If someone can solve this problem please let me know
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs because of `recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);`

swapAdapter is used to swap the adapter with a new one. You pass the same adapter so this call is useless. Even if you want to set a new adapter, Boolean parameter should be true to let RecyclerView recycle all existing Views.

Comment: using Boolean parameter true did not affect anything, the problem is in the **onScrolled** method  when I call the **getData** causes the items overlapping between the current list and the list of the selected category/item.

Comment: What about removing that line 'swapAdapter'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag when you are setting list in recycleview and set listener as per conditions

```
    protected void getRefreshView() {
    int childs = getChildCount();
    if (childs > 0) {
        View childView = getChildAt(0);
        if (childView instanceof RecyclerView) {
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) childView;
            mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);
            mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to...clear main list on each category click and restore that list for particulate category.

Comment: Why there's three recyclerview's? it's only one recyclerView in the app,
also we need the both method `onScrollStateChanged` and `onScrolled`